# Using Hive in real world applications?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am a newbee on Hadoop stack, I have learned map-reduce and now hive.

But I am not sure about hive use?

In map-R we have one or more output files n that's our final result, but In hive we can select the records using SQL like queries i.e. HQL but we are not getting any final output file. Results will be shown on terminal only.

Now my Q is how can we use this select HQL so that it can be used by some other analytic's team?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lot of ways to extract/export the hive query result outside.

If you want the result in any RDBMS storage you can use Sqoop.
I suggest you go through what Sqoop is and what it does.

And if you want your query results in a file, then there are lot of ways.
Hive supports exporting data from tables.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/home/lvermeer/temp' 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
select * from table;
```

Another simple approach would be to simple redirecting you hive query outputs to a file while running your hive queries in CLI.

```
hive -e "select * from table" > output.txt
```